# JNI -- UnsatisfiedLinkError on native method

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm running Windows XP.  Apparently JNI and UnsatisfiedLinkError go hand in hand...  I've noticed that most of the time, the linker error looks like this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no whatever.dll in java.library.path
```

But that's not my problem; Java can find my DLL.  I'm getting an error that makes me think i named my method wrong:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NativeTest.nativemethod(lJava/lang/String;)Z
```

I've tried looking at a number of similar questions on StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418346/another-jni-c-dll-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108612/unsatisfiedlinkerror-jni), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807665/unsatisfiedlinkerror-while-accessing-a-native-method), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166324/jni-unsatisfiedlinkerror), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905420/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-jni), but none of these methods have worked.  I also found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1104419) on the Ubuntu forums where it looks like the exact same problem i'm having, but the question asker didn't say how they fixed their own problem (which really sucks).  All Google searches on this have given me an error the same as the java.library.path one.

Here is my actual code.

**NativeTest.java**

```
class NativeTest
    {

    public static native boolean nativemethod (String arg);

    public static void main (String[] args)
        {
        System.out.println(nativemethod("0123456789"));
        System.out.println(nativemethod("012"));
        }

    static { System.loadLibrary("NativeTest"); }

    }
```

**NativeTest.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class NativeTest */

#ifndef _Included_NativeTest
#define _Included_NativeTest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     NativeTest
 * Method:    nativemethod
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_NativeTest_nativemethod
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**NativeTest.c**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "NativeTest.h"

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_NativeTest_nativemethod
    (JNIEnv* Jenv, jclass Jref, jstring Jarg)
    {
    MessageBox(NULL, "text", "title", MB_OK);
    int len = (*Jenv)->GetStringLength(Jenv, Jarg);
    return (jboolean)(len > 5);
    }
```

**In cmd.exe:**
(The gcc command is my hodgepodge of various commands i've found on the internet.)

```
>javac NativeTest.java

>javah -jni NativeTest

>gcc -shared -I<jdk_dir>\include -I<jdk_dir>\include\win32 -oNativeTest.dll NativeTest.c -lgdi32

>java -Djava.library.path=. NativeTest
Exception on thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NativeTest.nativemethod(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
        at NativeTest.nativemethod(Native Method)
        at NativeTest.main(NativeTest.java:8)

>java NativeTest
Exception on thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: NativeTest.nativemethod(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
        at NativeTest.nativemethod(Native Method)
        at NativeTest.main(NativeTest.java:8)
```

Comment: I haven't taken a close look at your code, but have you considered using JNA instead? Then you wouldn't have to worry about JNI's unfriendliness.

Comment: Didn't even know JNA existed.  I'll look into it.  Thanks :)

Comment: What is the package name you are using in your java code?

Comment: @rob I used JNA (Java Native Access). It's very useful and flexible!

Comment: @nuju glad you found it helpful!  Be sure to spread the word whenever you hear someone mention JNI or UnsatisfiedLinkError. JNI has its place, but JNA isn't nearly as painful to use.

Comment: Would be nice if you could flag my answer as correct if it indeed solves your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After messing around and googling to solve the same problem for half of the day, I have found that GCC does not generate DLLs where the JVM can resolve symbols. But one can pass the correct command line args to GCC and then it works:

See [this MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/node/41) post on the subject. One needs to pass "-D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at" as additional flags. Don't know if all of them are needed or just the first bit.

Comment: You sir, deserve more attention. I spent half a day trying to figure it out. Was about to ask a similar question on SO when I saw your answer.